# Why UILabel memory leak?

Tags: ios, xcode, object, memory-leaks, uilabel

When I try to set text on label the memory usage increased. Why this happens?

[image]

In simulator awesome

[image]

XCode Version 5.1.1 (5B1008), ARC

**[Resolved]**

Not memory leak but my misunderstanding

[image]

Comment: [No repro](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5reuI.png), although I'm surprised the app isn't just getting terminated for being unresponsive. More information is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the memory usage is growing is because this tight loop is creating new string allocation.  The device is never allow to exercise it retain cycle process.

Answer (score 0):

youre stuck in a while loop m8

Edit: i realize you know this, but when are you going to need to dominate the main thread to set a uilabel

Comment: Interesting, blocking main thread prevents memory disposal, I didn't know that, thx Michael.